# Image not displaying in mysqli php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Having code to fetch image from classic mysql this way which work greatly:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("front");
    $submit=$_GET['str'] ;
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM searcengine WHERE pagecontent LIKE '%$_GET[$submit]%' ");    
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
   echo "<img src=image_2.php?pagecontent=".$row['pagecontent']." />";
   }
?>
```

and image_2.php:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$conn)
{
echo mysql_error();
}
$db = mysql_select_db("front",$conn);
if(!$db)
{
echo mysql_error();
}
$pagecontent = $_GET['pagecontent'];
$q = "SELECT pageurl FROM searchengine where pagecontent='$pagecontent'";
$sql = mysql_query("$q",$conn);
if($sql)
{
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $row['pageurl'];
}
else
{
echo mysql_error();
}
?>
```

Now,i updated with latest mysqli code as follow:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","front");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
    $submit=$_GET['str'] ;

$sql="SELECT * FROM 'searchengine' WHERE 'pagecontent' = '%$submit%' ";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  // Fetch one and one row
 while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 echo "<img src=image_2.php?pagecontent=".$row['pagecontent']." />";
 }

  }
mysqli_close($con); 
?>
```

and image2.php=

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","front");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$pagecontent = $_GET['pagecontent'];
if (!empty($pagecontent)) {

$sql= "SELECT 'pageurl' FROM 'searchengine' where 'pagecontent'='$pagecontent'";
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $row['pageurl'];
}
?>
```

But in this case,i.e. image not displaying.Pls help what wrong am i?

Comment: Your first code example is horribly vulnerable to SQL injection, and it's using `mysql_query` which is a dead function. Do not use `mysql_*` functions, they have been deprecated for some time. See the huge red warning: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: indeed, it also doesnt make much sense. @125fura: Please create an MCVE : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @meagar and specializt ok i understand and not using them,it was just a way to make working,now why is my error?ANyhelp?

Comment: In the queries in your `mysqli` examples you have wrapped your SQL identifiers in apostrophes rather than backticks which is why they're failing. In your `mysql` versions you haven't used either so they work. You'd know this if you'd bothered to check the return status of your queries properly.

Comment: @HoboSapiens wait i'm trying your suggestion

Comment: You should read on [how to prevent SQL injections in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Comment: That is not the problem,i will do @gumbo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why to go open img in new file,try this:

```
<?php define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'front');
$conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
if (!$conn){ die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
exit;}
$submit=$_GET['str'];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT pageurl FROM searchengine WHERE pagecontent='%$submit%'");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $submit;
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($pageurl );
$stmt->fetch();
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
echo $pageurl ;?>
```

**Remember**: I replaced `*` from what are you searching as `pageurl` in your post.
Even,not work post your sql and form.

Comment: Thanks,but it will be better if i get image displayed using other file.

Comment: Oh,that easy just add a href and you can do.